# Using python to perform an Extract Transform and Load job

Tags: python, mysql

I am writing a simple program to help move data in between two mysql databases as an example i am moving data between two farmer table on each databases.

The following is the code i am trying out.

```
import MySQLdb, sys, pprint, io
from operator import not_

def ViewAllfarmers(myCon):

    cursor = myCon.cursor()

    cursor.execute(" SELECT farmermobile FROM adggtnz.reg02_maininfo")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print row[0];
        inserts(myCon,row[0])

    myCon.commit()  

def inserts(myCon,mobile):
    cursor = myCon.cursor()


    print str(mobile)
    strs="insert into adggtnz2.farmers(farmermobile) values ('"+mobile+"')"
    print strs
    cursor.execute(strs)


def main():

    host = '127.0.0.1'  # The MySQL Host
    port=3306 #mysql port
    user = 'root'  # The MySQL User name
    schema = 'adggtnz'  # The MySQL Schema name
    password = 'test'  # The MySQL User password

    try:
        myCon = MySQLdb.connect(host,user, password, schema,port)
        ViewAllfarmers(myCon)

    except MySQLdb.Error, e:
        print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])  # Print the error
        sys.exit(1)  # Exits with error


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The error to this code: I am unable to transfer any data into farmers table because of the following logical error

```
Rosemarijn
0613174066
insert into adggtnz2.reg01_maininfo(techname,techmobile ) values ('Rosemarijn','0613174066')
Error 1062: Duplicate entry '0613174066' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a Primary key and trying to add more than one value in `Primary Key` So you get this error. I think the problem is forget the identify `AUTO_INCREAMENT` to your Primary key row.

Comment: How can i ignore , i want to transfer my primary key to the new database i don't want to auto_increment